# Qt Creator not launching in OpenSUSE

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, opensuse

After a few years using Ubuntu, I decided to go back to OpenSUSE.  I installed Qt Creator using the online installer from Qt, along with all the framework versions I wanted.  Qt Creator refuses to launch.  When run from command line, is gives the following error:

```
static QPlatformTheme* QKdeTheme::createKdeTheme(): Unable to determine KDE dirs
```

I managed to install Qt 5 Creator from repositories on OpenSUSE, and this one runs.  I can't tell the difference between it and the one from Qt (which I used on Ubuntu).

This version of Qt Creator gives the same error as above, but in the Application Output window every time I run an application.

Any idea what causes this?  Or how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the kde directory trees into the KDEDIRS environment variable  of your system. In order to do this you can do the following:

1. List the kde directory trees, by executing the command `kde4-config --path config`.
2. Edit the config file of your connection shell to set the KDEDIRS variable with the output of the above command.

Done!. Reboot your system and hopefully, you will not get this error message each time you run your program with your connection shell running.